# Hackable WiFi-enabled LED lightbulb

Tags: wifi, smart-device, home-electronics

I'd like to replace my home lightbulbs for bulbs with on-board WiFi. I want to be able to control them with my custom "smart home" application.

Bonus points if it let's me to control R/G/B channels separately.

Does anyone have experience with such a product?

Comment: There are many options, but I'm not going to put this down as an answer because I don't have experience with the products as requested: http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&IsNodeId=1&N=100161776%20601204663%20601204630

Comment: I ended up ordering [LIFX](http://www.lifx.com/), which provides an open API and devkit. Will update after getting my hands on it. https://github.com/LIFX